# Prevent console logging when emitting data with sockets

Tags: node.js

how can I prevent node from outputting the data that I emit using io.sockets.emit(...)? I am not manually logging the data. I expect to have hundreds of users connecting to the node server, so I don't want the terminal window going crazy. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set log level option to 0 like this:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port, host);
io.set('log level', 0);
```